# Using device_preview package is throwing error in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to use **device_preview** package so that I could preview my flutter app on all kind of devices but whenever.

I use **device_preview** package it throws me some errors. Does anyone have any idea why am I getting this error?

Here's my code.

```
import 'package:book_a_ride/screens/landing_screen/landing_screen.dart';
import 'package:book_a_ride/screens/verification_screen/verification_screen.dart';
import 'package:book_a_ride/ui/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:device_preview/device_preview.dart';


void main() => runApp(
  DevicePreview(
    enabled: kReleaseMode,
    builder: (context)=>BookARide(),
  ),
);

class BookARide extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
              builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
              home: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: SafeArea(
                  child: LandingScreen(),
                ),
              ),
              theme: ThemeData.light(),
              initialRoute: LandingScreen.id,
              routes: {
                LandingScreen.id: (context) => LandingScreen(),
                HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
                VerificationScreen.id: (context) => VerificationScreen(),
              },
            );
          }
}

name: book_a_ride
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  device_preview:
#  url_launcher:
#  //google_maps_flutter:
#  location:
#  geolocator:


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**The error being displayed:**

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/device_preview-0.4.8/lib/src/device_preview.dart:135:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
          nullOk: nullOk,
          ^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  **`Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991`**
- What went wrong:
  **`Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.`**

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

  ```
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ```
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 17s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ flutter clean` and then again rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

you need this in MaterialApp for device preview to work

useInheritedMediaQuery: true,

Comment: useInheritedMediaQuery this in now deprecated. Is there another way?